# Join a cached query (sql,nosql, or whatever exist on earth)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, caching, elasticsearch, nosql

After 1 month of research , question rest unresolved.
I need to cache a part of query in a join, innerjoin or whatever.
**edit** : the subquery in above example is a geo search who select all post code in a radius search , thoses querys result never change)
Example :

```
SELECT complex things who never be cached 
INNER JOIN ( select SQL_CACHE all things easely cached and unmodified )
```

As far as i know **mysql** cannot perform that,
**maria db** can cache subquery sometimes with IN , but not with JOIN things .

My only actual solution is terrific :

**put in memcached :**

```
select SQL_CACHE very things cached and unmodified
```

**implode the resulted array :**

```
$bob=('a','b','c');
```

**Then make a the 2step query :**

```
SELECT complex things who never be cached IN ($bob);
```

This is not a solution because I can have 30000 item in the IN list..

I am totaly open for any solution or advises 
regards,
bob

Comment: In Postgres, try: `create materialized view as ...`

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new table inside your database that you use as "cache" for your results, that are not modified. This way you can easily join with any other data you have in your database.

Comment: this is unfortunatly impossible because the subquery is a geo search query with many possibility indeed, paris 50km is different of paris 400km .. So the prequery should be in cache, create and open a ton of tables are not possible from a performance point of vue

Comment: so you would store the results depending on the distance? I guess its almost impractible since you can have almost unlimited combinations of source lat/lon and distance combination. Why not try to optimize your geo search?

Comment: theres notunlimited solution, search are rounded and approximatived , there are many possibility but not unlimited, geo search is really widly optimised and all other process possible solutions ever been tested..:)

Comment: well then... it's almost impossible to offer an almost good solution with that little information about the whole thing...